# Get the source into a string from the next page after a POST

Tags: c#

I am posting data to a form and all works well, but afterwards I need to get the source(html) of the page where it reffers to after I POST'ed the data.

Is this possible and if so how?

I am using this method to POST:

```
 string HttpPost(string uri, string parameters)
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(parameters);
        Stream os = null;
        try
        {
            webRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;   
            os = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
            os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);         
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "HttpPost: Request error",
               MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (os != null)
            {
                os.Close();
            }
        }

        try
        { 
            WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
            if (webResponse == null)
            { return null; }
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
            return sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "HttpPost: Response error",
               MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: `return sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();`

This thing will return the content of the page on which you just posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you want the response from the server? If so, read the documentation for `HttpWebRequest`, particularly the `GetResponse` method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx

Edited: thanks for posting sourcecode now. That's the basic structure you need, so I'm unclear what your question is...

Comment: No, I want to read the source of the next page that comes up. (How a browser would react if it posted something and it goes to the next page)

Comment: That's (basically) the same thing as the response from the server. The response from the server supplies the HTML (or other content) that your browser uses to construct the next page.

Comment: Ah I thought the response of the server replied a code such as "Error 404" and such. But thank you I will try this out tomorrow :)

Comment: That's also true (hence my 'basically') - the response contains a header (with the status code and other information) then the actual content (if any). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol